# AWK output to a delimited string

Tags: awk, gawk

The following

`awk/\-0.81/ { print $0 }' fullYearData.txt`

successfully finds the instances of

`-0.81`

In a long list of lines, like this:

```
2017-01-10 16:58   0.90 feet  Low Tide
2017-01-10 22:54   2.10 feet  High Tide
2017-01-11 07:19  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
2017-01-11 14:15   1.06 feet  High Tide
2017-01-11 17:48   0.89 feet  Low Tide
2017-01-11 23:42   2.13 feet  High Tide
2017-01-12 08:03  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
2017-01-12 14:51   1.06 feet  High Tide
```

Output:

```
2017-01-11 07:19  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
2017-01-12 08:03  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
```

How can I manage to output the result (2 lines in this case) in a single line, like this:

```
2017-01-11 07:19  -0.81 feet  Low Tide, 2017-01-12 08:03  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
```

Comment: You don't have to escape `-` in your pattern as it does not have a special meaning except  when used in ranges like `[a-c]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to introduce a field separator variable `f` that is set after the first match.

```
awk '/-0.81/{s=s f $0; f=", "} END{print s}' fullYearData.txt
```

Initially, both variables `s` and `f` will contain the empty string ("").

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '/-0.81/{if(!a)a=$0; else a=a", "$0} END{print a}' fullYearData.txt
2017-01-11 07:19  -0.81 feet  Low Tide, 2017-01-12 08:03  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
```

Or even shorter:

```
awk '/-0.81/{a=!a ? $0 : a", "$0} END{print a}' fullYearData.txt
```

Append the matching lines to a variable (`a`) and at the `END`, print the variable `a`. Initially `a` would be zero and the `if-else` check is used to decide when a `,` needs to be added (i.e not for the first time, but add `,` for subsequent pattern matched lines.

Comment: The `\n` in `printf` unnecessarily bounds `awk` to specific implementations because different distributions handle escape sequences differently. `print a` is just enough here and would  make a more general solution.

Answer (score 1):

Another awk solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{old_ORS=ORS;ORS=", "}/-0.81/{print}END{ORS=old_ORS;print}' fullYearData.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Buffer output to `b` and print in the `END`:

```
$ awk '/-0.81/{b=b (b==""?"":", ") $0}END{print b}' file
2017-01-11 07:19  -0.81 feet  Low Tide, 2017-01-12 08:03  -0.81 feet  Low Tide
```

Answer (score 1):

simply print filter line without CR/LF (with a ", " after first occurence, the most difficult part here)

```
awk '/-0.81/{printf( "%s%s", ! a++ ? "" : ", ", $0)}' YourFile

# with final new line if needed
awk '/-0.81/{printf( "%s%s", ! a++ ? "" : ", ", $0)}END{print}' YourFile
```